# Macro code is sending unexpected shift key down and up for no reason

Tags: autohotkey

The following macro code is very simple for a game that im playing, When RB button on the controller is pressed, Two keyboard buttons need to be pressed and when the RB button is released the two other keyboard keys needs also to be released.
Somehow,I don't know why, Shift key is also pressed down and up when i release the RB button.
**IMPORTENT NOTE:** In the game there are no key binding for the Shift key (so that is not the case).
Please help me figure out why is the shift key is pressed and how the hell this key is related to my code even though i didn't use it.
the code:

```
keystate := 0

Joy6::
{
    send {X down}
    send {C down}
    loop
    {
        keystate := GetKeyState("Joy6","P")
        if(keystate == 0)
        {
            send {X up}
            send {C up}
            Break
        }   
    }
}
return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Note](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Parameters): As capital letters are produced by sending the Shift key, A
>   produces a different effect in some programs than a.

Try replacing the capitals **X,C** in the send commands with their lowercase **x,c**.